# MVC framework for wxPython

Tags: python, model-view-controller, wxpython

I'm an electrical engineer have a large ongoing project in python.It was my first time programming GUI , I picked wxPython in first and continue with that as it was easy to learn.I always had the concern of separating my data from the presentation and I just learnt that is MVC framework:) Now I want to change my code to follow MVC rules but I couldnt find any for wxPython. There is pyQt that has this but I want that to be my last solution since I dont have the time to sit and learn that.

Do you happen to know a wxPython MVC framework to use ?

Answer (score 6):

There is no framework per se, although I suppose Dabo might be an option for you since it abstracts the database stuff and the GUI stuff: http://dabodev.com/

On the other hand, there are articles about MVC and wxPython:

- http://wiki.wxpython.org/ModelViewController
- http://wiki.wxpython.org/wxPython%20Patterns
- http://www.blog.pythonlibrary.org/2011/11/10/wxpython-and-sqlalchemy-an-intro-to-mvc-and-crud/
- http://www.blog.pythonlibrary.org/2011/11/30/improving-medialocker-wxpython-sqlalchemy-and-mvc/

Hopefully one of those will help you along. You can also ask on the wxPython Google Group. They may have other suggestions.